# linux bash 'sort' in dictionary order

Tags: linux, bash, file, sorting, unix

I am trying to sort a file, in ascending order. The file has both alphabets and numerical values.

```
aae-miR-1
aae-miR-10
aae-miR-100
aae-miR-1000
aae-miR-11-3p
aae-miR-11-5p
aae-miR-1174
aae-miR-1175-3p
aae-miR-1175-5p
aae-miR-12-3p
aae-miR-124
```

I want the output as

```
aae-miR-1
aae-miR-10
aae-miR-11-3p
aae-miR-11-5p
aae-miR-12-3p
aae-miR-100
aae-miR-124
aae-miR-1000
aae-miR-1174
aae-miR-1175-3p
aae-miR-1175-5p`
```

I used,

```
sort -k1,1 -n <file>
```

For sorting, with numeric and alphabetical order, but it is not coming as expected. Please suggest, the use of `sort`

Comment: Try specifying dash as the field separator, and use numeric sort.

Comment: Using filed-separator will break the element in two. This is only a part of my file, if I separate all by "-" the file will become much problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `sort -t"-" -k3n file.txt` for this case.

Output received :-

```
aae-miR-1
aae-miR-10
aae-miR-11-3p
aae-miR-11-5p
aae-miR-12-3p
aae-miR-100
aae-miR-124
aae-miR-1000
aae-miR-1174
aae-miR-1175-3p
aae-miR-1175-5p
```

> This is more explicit. **`'-t'`** option is used to provide the
>   delimiter in case of files with delimiter. '-k' is used to specify the
>   keys on the basis of which the sorting has to be done. The format of
>   '-k' is : **`-km[,n]`** where m is the starting key and n is the ending key. n is an optional key,used only when required.

Comment: Thank you, it works. What does, `-k3n,3` does in here ?

Comment: @MANAUWERRAZA-The format of `'-k' is : '-km,n'` where m is the starting key/column and n is the ending key/column.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sort -n -t- -k3 <file>
```

- `-n` will numerically sort.
- `-t-` will use `-` as field separator.
- `-k3` will use third field to sort by.

Comment: Thank you, it was wise, to split using field separator, and then `-k3` for the 3rd field sort

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with separator:

```
sort -t - -k3n file
```